# Scroll automático al final del div

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un chat simple, con php y ajax. Al momento en que se ingresan muchos datos aparece el scroll, pero quiero que baje automáticamente, ¿Cómo podría realizar esto?

En mi index.php es donde se muestra el chat, mi codigo es asi

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);
$id=$_GET['id'];
var_dump($id);

comprobarSession();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/functions.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            ajaxcall();
            $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var dataen = $("#form").serialize() + "&action";// the action here is for if(isset($_POST['action'])){do this}

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'inser.php',
                        data:dataen,
                        success:function(response){
                            if (response == "") {}
                            ajaxcall();
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
        // Calls read.php file
        function ajaxcall(){

        var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value;// the $us
        $.ajax({
            url: 'chat.php?id='+myId,// url where you will get the data
            success: function(data) {//  means if success do this
                    $('#chat').html(data);// id of the element that the data will be shown
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat"> AQUI ES DONDE SE MUESTRA EL CHAT</div>
    </div>
    <form id="form">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it" id="submit">

        <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="idEmitter" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

y el chat.php esta asi

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT ue.nombre de, ur.nombre a, c.message FROM  messages c
        INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
        INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
        WHERE (c.idEmitter = $id AND c.idReceiver = $us)
        OR (c.idEmitter = $us AND c.idReceiver = $id)
        ORDER BY sent ASC";

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
imprimir($arrDatos);

//Una función para mostrar los datos
function imprimir($arrDatos)
{
    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br>';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["a"].': </span>'.'<br>'.$row["message"].'<br>';
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.'<br>'.$row["message"].'<br>';
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}
?>
```

ahora, he investigado y encontre este foro

[Donde muestra un ejemplo de que el scroll siempre este hasta abajo](http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/JQuery/1437480-como-bajar-scroll-automaticamente.html) pero el problema es que yo intente integrar la solucion y no me da, no me mostraba ningun error ni nada, solo no funcionaba

Comment: Hola Cesar. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado. Si no has probado aun, investiga por tu cuenta e intenta implementarlo. Si en el proceso tienes dudas, pregunta aqui. Por el momento, esta pregunta es muy amplia. Para más información tienes la guia [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: La parte php en realidad no es tan importante en este problema, pero sí deberíamos poder ver el html/css y el javascript para poder orientarte y ayudarte. Échale un vistazo a [ask] y en la medida de lo posible aporta un [mcve].

Comment: @Muriano he editado mi pregunta

Comment: Si, pero el codigo que nos interesa es el que has intentado respecto a lo que preguntas. Muestra ese intento de integracion que mencionas al final para sobre eso poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ajeno a la pregunta realizada, ten cuidado con esa consulta a la base de datos, es sensible a SQL Injection. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL

Answer (score 2):

Podrías poner para que al ser exitosa el request AJAX se haga un scroll hasta abajo de la pantalla si es que el chat está abajo de todo:

```
// Calls read.php file
function ajaxcall(){
    var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat.php?id=' + myId,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#chat').html(data); // Cargas la informacion
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000); // Scrollea hasta abajo de la página 
        }
    });
}
```

En el caso en que el que el scroll sea propio del div podrías remplazar la línea que agregué por esta:

```
$("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000); // Scrollea hasta abajo del div, el id debe ser del div que tiene la barra de scrolleo
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hola Luis Vicente, aunque este código podría servir para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle. Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.